# Switch-case statement in C++ not calling functions

Tags: c++

I'm new to **C++** and I'm trying to make a **project on student management system**. The problem here is that when I run the code and select an option, it **doesn't display anything**. Please point out my mistake here. Also, if there are any other suggestions, in general, please let me know!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class OTHERS
{
public:
    void newAccount();
    void login();
    void delAccount();
    void update();
    void search_acc();
};

void OTHERS::newAccount()
{
    cout << "\nIn newAccount";
}

void OTHERS::login()
{
    cout << "\nEnter Student ID: ";
    cout << "\nEnter Student Passcode: ";
}

void OTHERS::delAccount()
{
    cout << "\nIn delAccount";
}

void OTHERS::update()
{
    cout << "\nIn update";
}

void OTHERS::search_acc()
{
    cout << "\nIn search_acc";
}


class HOME
{
public:
    int opt;
    int options()
    {
        cout << "\n\t\t\t\t\tWelcome!";
        cout << "\nChoose one option: " << opt;
        cout << "\n1. Login \n2. Create New Account \n3. Delete Account \n4. Update Account \n5. Search Account";
        cout << "\n->";
        cin >> opt;

        switch (opt)
        {
        case 1:
            void login();
            break;
        case 2:
            void newAccount();
            break;
        case 3:
            void delAccount();
            break;
        case 4:
            void update();
            break;
        case 5:
            void sreach_acc();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "\nChoose a valid option! Try again...";
            options();
            break;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    HOME h;
    OTHERS o;
    h.options();

    return 0;
}
```

(I'm using CodeBlocks)

Comment: You should look into how to call a function vs. declare a function. `void update();` is not *calling* `update`.

Comment: Remove the voids from your cases

Comment: Try `login();` instead of `void login();`. And read your compiler warnings as they would have told you exactly what the problem was.

Comment: a general advice: if one detail is not working as you expect then write some code that has only that detail not more. This will help you to see what the issue is. Sometimes you have to experiment a bit and remove parts of the code and maybe add them back again to see if they are related to the problem. For example here the `switch` does not really matter. Coincidentally, if you write such minimal example code that not only can help you to find the problem, but it is also a [mcve] you can post here. Cheers & happy coding :)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Appreciate your advice!

Comment: @crashmstr and *3Dave* I got rid of 'void' but code blocks displays this error in the switch statement: "newAccount() was not declared in this scope". This same error is being displayed for all functions.

Comment: If you found a solution to your own question, it is perfectly acceptable to post an answer to your own question, and mark that answer as "correct". This will remove your Q from the list of "open" questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by creating an object of class OTHERS in the private section of class HOME and simply calling functions using that object.

Answer (score -2):

Why do you use an int with options switch it to a void like
`void options()`

also why do you do this? it seems unnecessary.
`<< opt;`

also use inheritance such as this

`class HOME : public OTHERS`

and don't forget to delete the voids

also I switched from a switch statement to a do while loop